# Restore mistakenly deleted rewrite.load from /etc/apache2

Tags: apt, apache2

I just incidentally deleted `/etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load` how do I restore it? I tried `apt reinstall apache2`, but it did not help.

Comment: From a recent backup ?

Comment: There is no backup, the server was just installed

Comment: Mine contains exactly this: `LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so` . So there you go.

Comment: @Jos I am confused, because do not know the relation between .so and .load files.

Comment: use `dpkg -S /etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load` to see which package installed it, then re-install that.

Comment: @guiverc `apache2` installed the file, and reinstalling this package did not help

Comment: The `.load` file in this case simply instructs how to load the module `mod_rewrite.so`. It's simply a text file.

Answer (score 4):

It's just a text file with the following content in Xenial:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

You can look for the file in [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com).

It is the piece of configuration that loads the binary module responsible for URL rewriting (the .so file). Apache (Nginx does that too) stores these files in a "mods-available" directory, so you can enable and disable it at will. To enable a module, you should create a symbolic link pointing to the .load file inside the "mods-enabled", or use the a2enmod utility, like that:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

To disable a module, use:

```
sudo a2dismod rewrite
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

If you pay attention, you'll see that the a2dismod/a2enmod deletes/creates the symbolic link for you.

In the end, it's just a way to make Apache's configuration more dynamic and easier to manage.